# Output of list.append prints word "array" after each iteration

Tags: python, arrays, list, append

I want to make a list in python, consisting of different entries. Each entry to the list occurs a different number of times:

```
import numpy as np
frequency = (1, 2, 1, 2, 1)
numbers = np.random.choice(9, size = (5, 3), replace=True)
list = []

for i in range(0, 5):
    list.append(np.tile(numbers[i], (int(frequency[i]), 1)))
print(list)
```

This works fine. However, when I look at the output (print(list)), I get the following:

```
[array([[1, 8, 1]]), array([[2, 8, 0],
   [2, 8, 0]]), array([[6, 8, 6]]), array([[2, 1, 8],
   [2, 1, 8]]), array([[4, 6, 1]])]
```

Why does it include the word "array" for every iteration? I would just like to have a list like this:

```
[[1 8 1]
[2 8 2]
[2 8 2]
[6 8 6]
[2 1 8]
[2 1 8]
[4 6 1]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Why does it include the word "array" for every iteration?*

You have `list` of `numpy.array`s as `numpy.tile` function does return `numpy.array`.

*I would just like to have a list like this:*

Desired output suggest that you are looking for single 2D array, which could be created from `list` of 1D arrays using `numpy.vstack` function. Consider following example:

```
import numpy as np
mylist = [np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([4,5,6]),np.array([7,8,9])]
myarray = np.vstack(mylist)
print(myarray)
```

Output:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```

As side note: please do not python built-ins function names as variables

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using two different types of data - classic python list and numpy list. When you are printing an classic list it will show you `[a, b, c]`, but for numpy list it will show you an `array([a, b, c])`